# Separating data fromin UI window forms

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I am creating my first Windows Forms project, and I am looking for a little advice.  Right now, I have two forms.  One gets product information from a user, and the other displays it in   a table.  I have an inventory class that contains a collection of products.  I imagine that the forms should not instantiate this collection, they should merely have access to it.  But if this is the case, where do I instantiate my inventory class?  And once I do, how do I pass data from this class to my forms?  Note that I am not allowed to use data binding.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use singleton pattern here. Read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).
For example

```
public class Inventory
{
private Inventory instance;

private Inventory() {}
public Inventory Instance { get {
if(instance == null) instance = new Inventory();
return instance;
} 
}

//other code goes here
```

}

And later each your form can access single instance of this class and work with it `Inventory.Instance.someMethod()`

Comment: Are there any methods that do not introduce a global state into my program?

Comment: You can follow advice below and create DAL layer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're asking about a data access layer (DAL).

This kind of layer can be either physically (in different assemblies) or logically (in the same assembly, but different namespaces) separated layer built into the application to abstract the source of data from the rest of your application. This data source could be a database, some external text file, or simply hard-coded data.

Consider the following example:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ProductsDAL
{
    public static IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        return new List<Product>(new Product[]
            { 
                new Product() { Id = 1 },
                new Product() { Id = 2 }
            });
    }
}
```

In the above example the ProductsDAL class would handle abstracting where the data came from away from the object that called it to get at that information. Most DAL classes have methods for creating, reading, updating, and deleting the objects that they're used to access (commonly referred to as CRUD).

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    private IEnumerable<Product> products;

    private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.products = ProductsDAL.GetProducts();
    }
}
```

Using the DAL class, you can request it to retrieve the products from whatever source it's using, and load that information onto your form. What you want to do with that information once you have it is entirely up to you. You could very well iterate through the products available, and load them into combo boxes, a grid, whatever your scenario would require.

Using this approach you'd be able to replace the source of the data, from say the hard-coded list in my example, to accessing a database and some tables to pull the data later. In which case you'd simply replace the hard-coded list in the ProductsDAL.GetProducts method with your database call.